# What is the meaning of “appreciate the injustice”?

Tags: meaning

> At the time, Mariam did not understand. She did not know what this word – harami-bastard – meant.
>   Nor was she old enough to appreciate the injustice.

In the above, what is the meaning of the term *appreciate the injustice*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is dependent on a specific meaning of appreciate

[appreciate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/appreciate) - to understand a situation and realize that it is important:

so the sentence

> Nor was she old enough to appreciate the injustice.

can be taken to mean

> Nor was she old enough to understand that there had been an injustice.

Comment: Yes; I think the latter is the more likely meaning. Who can really fully understand justice / injustice? But it's not easy to find a dictionary giving the latter sense.  [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/appreciate) gives << **appreciate** [vt] (2a) to be fully aware of / (2b) to be [highly] sensitive to //// (2c) to realize [that something is involved in the situation] >> (I think the adaptations are legitimate). // Ah, RHK Webster's gives 'to be aware of, detect'. ////// I can't upvote unless you cite / attribute (CED here) correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the context, it means that Mariam was too young to understand how bad/severe the word was particularly to her as the child/innocent victim of circumstance that she was being called names for.

This style of writing is often used by joining a word with a positive connotation next to one with a negative connotation to create emphasis. 
For e.g - My teacher is fantastically ignorant. It is more dramatic than just saying he is ignorant.

Comment: The use of "appreciate" isn't employing any device, nor does "appreciate" have any positive connotation in this sense.  The author is using "appreciate" literally, in exact accordance with one of its dictionary definitions (i.e., 3. to be fully conscious of; be aware of; detect - https://www.dictionary.com/browse/appreciate?s=t ).